# Is there a Maven "compiler-only" scope for dependency artifacts

Tags: java, maven, semantics

I realise this is more of a semantic quest rather than a functionality quest.

I have three types of compile-scope dependencies:

1. Compile-only scope, not used at run-time.
   GWT client-side dev, MVP4G, RestyGWT, Source retention annotation processors. I use REST, so I don't need GWT server side.
2. Provided - Hibernate jars required for compilation but provided by JBoss.
3. Compile + runtime jars.

For case 2, we could use provided scope. Case 3, we would use compile scope.

However for case 1, I use provided scope, even though JBoss does not provide those files at all. Nor are they needed at run-time.

Anyway, don't you think Maven should provide for a synonym for "provided" for a scope where the artefacts are not really needed except at compile time? Perhaps, should there be a "compile-only" scope?

Comment: Someone edited the title to "Is there a Maven “compiler dependencies” scope for libraries required by build tools (not javac)" which is not appropriate. Firstly, javac is involved (due to annotation processor for source retention policies). 2ndly, the Maven term is "artifacts" and I intend to use the precise term of "artifacts" rather than "libraries".

Comment: Therefore, I am changing the title back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the jars with are not true "runtime" dependencies (only for building) but not for the final artifact, you can exclude them various means:

1. Exclusion in the assembly descriptor
2. Exclusion in the jar (or war, ear, whatever) plugin configuration
3. [Shade Plugin minimize jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) goal

I agree that shipping unnecessary classes is annoying (I've seen junit and testng jars in production deployments - brrrr...), but for all practical purposes it's a rather minor one.

If you have a dependency conflict (i.e shipping a "all deps" version of a library or framework), that's a different story, but doesn't sound like what you're facing here.

Comment: Deploying a 15MB war vs 150MB war is a huge convenience/advantage/emailability.

Comment: In that case, you want option #3

Comment: its not minor at all!   
additional jar's in production introduce security risks

Comment: Could also introduce issues with licenses. Using something internally for code-generation/compilation/test and giving something as end-product to a paying customer is two different things (I think, I am not a lawyer)

Answer (score 17):

If a dependency is only used for building, such as an annotation processor, it should be a maven `<plugin>`, or `<dependency>` thereof.

Otherwise, if it is in the compilation classpath, it will be necessary for linking the generated class file at runtime. Then, there are two cases:

1. It is always necessary to load that class

   1. the class should be shipped as part of the application: `<scope>compile</scope>`
   2. the class should be provided by the runtime environment: `<scope>provided</scope>`
2. It is sometimes necessary (because that class will be loaded only under particular circumstances): `<optional>true</optional>`

The only option not covered is compiling a Java program, and never running it in a JVM. This is a really obscure use case, and I can't fault the designers of maven for not including a scope just to express this distinction - particularly since it is irrelevant to Maven's core responsibility (building the software).

Comment: Do you mean to say that Maven did/does not intend to give proper treatment to source-retention annotation processors? I suppose JDK 5 annotation came long after Maven, but Maven 3 should have taken that into account.

Comment: No, and I don't see how you get that impression. I clearly write in  the second paragraph that annotation processors should be plugins. I certainly did not call that improper treatment.

Comment: I wrote **maven plugin**, not Jenkins plugin.

Comment: I do have them as plugins, but the annotation namespace still has to be visible thro a dependency during development. Amd such a dependency should be compile-only scope. Is there a way to skip having a dependency on the annotation definition interface in the pom?

Comment: Ah, you're not worried about the annotation processor, but the annotation class file? Annotations with Retention.SOURCE are rare, most people don't worry about having them needlessly in the classpath, so there isn't a special scope for them.

Comment: @meriton, some years later I can add: (1) it's not only about SOURCE, the same applies also to `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` and (2) some people appear to be very strict on avoiding even just a few kilobytes of annotation types in their deployment.

Comment: Note that the reasons for the strictness is typically not the kilobytes, but license compliance and security. Noone wants to get sued for distributing something they are not permitted to, or open additional routes to inject malware into their distributions.