# How to tell the project to download internal dependency?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a JAR. It is not a FAT JAR. It only contains my classes. But my JAR has a dependency upon azure-servicebus. I don't want to add azure-servicebus to my jar and make it a fat jar.

I just want that when the project adds my jar, it should download azure-servicebus automatically.

I am using Maven to create a jar (without dependencies).

How do I specify that? Is this possible?

edit:

I want the project that is adding my jar as a dependency should download azure-servicebus WITHOUT project having to add dependency for azure-servicebus or me packaging azure-servicebus within the jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question without knowing something very important.

When jars are put into artifactory, a corresponding .pom file also has to be placed alongside it (outside of the directory). This pom file is what tells the dependent project that the jar you are dependent upon, requires so and so dependencies itself.

This answer helped me understand:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002072/4828463

Thanks to everyone who tried.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a maven structue in your project, you would add the following line to your `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't have a maven structure, you'd need to generate one. This usually can be achieved within the IDE you're using.

If you want the resulting jar not having the service-bus, you can make the dependency some kind of compile only, which would be more or less a duplicate of this question: [Is there a Maven "compiler-only" scope for dependency artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824112/is-there-a-maven-compiler-only-scope-for-dependency-artifacts) .

However, this would imply that your target runtime has to include the definition for the classes in some way (via -cp switch maybe).

From my POV: If you need a dependency to run your program, include it as long as the licence allows that.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want. I want the project that is adding my jar as a dependency should download azure-servicebus WITHOUT project having to add dependency for azure-servicebus or me packaging azure-servicebus with the jar file.

Comment: @FarazDurrani How should that work? That sounds like a contradiction in itself?...

Comment: @khmarbaise no. I will write my own answer. I was able to solve it.

Comment: @khmarbaise I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the structure you are talking about is:

`some-project` depends on `your-jar` which depends on `azure-servicebus`.

If `some-project` declares a Maven dependency on `your-jar`, then it gets `azure-servicebus` automatically as dependency because Maven does transitive dependency resolution. So when you build `some-project`, `azure-servicebus` will be on the class-path and if `some-project` is a WAR/EAR, than `azure-servicebus` will be part of that WAR/EAR.