# Which is gradle's compileOnly equivalent in maven scope?

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I want to mention following dependency in maven , which is included in gradle as :

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compileOnly('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
```

So I know for compile we have `<scope>compile</scope>` in maven.

but how to mention **compileOnly**? I havent seen compileOnly scope in maven.

Comment: Maybe `provided`?

Comment: According to [this blog](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies), `provided` in Maven is closest to Gradle's new compile only.

Comment: Hello @PramodNikam , This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824112/is-there-a-maven-compiler-only-scope-for-dependency-artifacts

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You should turn your comment into an answer and prepare to receive upvotes.

Comment: @thokuest The thing is, that blog post sounds way better than anything I could write :-)